# How do Java Priority Queues Work Under The Hood?

Tags: java, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I cannot seem to find any information to answer my question. So Java [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) are built using heaps. Heaps have an insertion and deletion time of O(logn) so if I were to do a heap sort that would be O(nlogn).

But during creation of a heap it only takes O(n) time. So lets say I put the line

```java
PriorityQueue<Character> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(list);
```

Is Java building the data structure with the values so its O(n) or is it inserting afterwards so its O(nlogn)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check the source: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java

When you initialize it from an unsorted list, it uses the O(n) `heapify` method.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you happen to know why the people who developed the code for priority queue did not include a constructor that takes in a list and a custom comparator? I'm assuming you cannot build a heap using a custom comparator?

Comment: There's no good reason.  You can build a heap with a custom comparator just fine.